# Is it possible to disable firewall on WNDR3400?

Tags: networking, router

I have my home network configured with several routers, to provide different protection zones:

```
                          WAN
                           |
+=============+     +=============+     +=============+
| 192.168.1.x |-----| 192.168.2.x |-----+ 192.168.3.x |
+=============+     +=============+     +=============+
```

- The 1.x network is my "inner" zone, where the assumption is that all attached machines are friendly. There's a NAT router acting as firewall from the "outer" network.
- The 2.x network is controlled by the FiOS ActionTec. An OK router, but it's configured to phone home and report things such as the admin password. Right now it's set up with random passwords all around and no wifi.
- The 3.x network is my "outer" network, for guest computers, internet radio, the TV, &c. The devices attached to it are not trusted,  but the router itself is assumed to be trustworthy.

What I'd like to do is make an SSH connection from a machine on the 1.x network to a machine on the 3.x network (ie, to my work laptop).

I can do this with assigning a static IP to the laptop and setting up a port forward in the WNDR3400, but this limits me to one machine. I could also bridge the WNDR3400 to the ActionTec, and get rid of the 3.x network entirely (and this is probably where I'll end up).

But what I'd like to do is configure the WNDR3400 to accept all inbound traffic -- in other words, to behave like a router. Then I could set up a routing rule in the ActionTek to direct 3.x traffic to it. However, I haven't been able to find anything in the config that would let me do this (LinkSys had a Router/Gateway drop-down, DD-WRT gives you several routing options).

Installing DD-WRT isn't an option because it's a WNDR3400.**v3**, and DD-WRT only claims to work on a **.v1**. I don't know if any other third-party firmware would work.

Is there an option other than bridging the ActionTec and WNDR3400?

Comment: So basically you want to disable NAT on the WNDR3400, possibly with proper firewalling and whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB - yeah, that's another way to put it. In fact, I don't need firewall functionality from that router at all -- the ActionTec is the Internet gateway. There's no need to protect anything on the 3.x network.

Answer (score 1):

#### I can do this with assigning a static IP to the laptop and setting up a port forward in the WNDR3400, but this limits me to one machine.

You can use **Port Triggering** instead (provided you don't require multiple simultaneous SSH connections.

---

#### Configuring Port Triggering

> Port triggering is a dynamic extension of port forwarding that is
>   useful in these cases:
>
> - **More than one local computer needs port forwarding for the same application (but not simultaneously**).

Source [N600 Wireless Dual Band Router WNDR3400 User Manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3400V1/WNDR3400_UM_31AUG2010.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I do occasionally have multiple computers on the 3.x network. Also, port triggering requires an outbound connection to enable the inbound.